moving into parallel compound intervals counterpoint
in strict counterpoint and i'm talking about fux's book
is having 2 parallel perfect intervals with contrary motion still wrong?
because in fux book only contrary and oblique motion are acceptable for perfect intervals

the voice leading below seems satisfying to my ear tho and looks like a good motion to me

I wonder if you asked what you meant to ask, since there seems to be a contradiction in the question?

Thank to my friend that cleared it out for me and i realized  it's such a stupid question . Sometimes just digging so deep into these theory stuff makes me dumb

Lol, it does to all of us!


is having 2 parallel perfect intervals with contrary motion still wrong?

No, it is impossible because the definition of "parallel perfect interval" includes that the motion is parallel.  If the motion is contrary, there are no parallel perfect intervals.

in fux book only contrary and oblique motion are acceptable for perfect intervals

Exactly.  Contrary motion is acceptable.  Question answered.
